# Laravel 5.2 Custom validation message with custom validation function

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I want to create custom validation rule with custom validation error message. For this  I created a rule:

```
$rule => [
    'app_id' => 'isValidTag'
]
```

And for custom message:

```
$message => [
   app_id.isValidTag   => 'Not a Valid id'
];
```

After that I created Service Provider:

```
class CustomValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {

    //parent::boot();

    $this->app->validator->resolver(function($transator,$data,$rules,$messages){
            return new CustomValidator($transator,$data,$rules,$messages);
        });
    }
}
```

And my Custom validation class is:

```
class CustomValidator extends Validator {
    if(empty($parameters)) {
        return true;
    }

    $conext = $parameters[0];
    $tag = Tag::where('id', $value)->where('context', $conext)->get();

    $flag = false;
    if($tag->count() > 0) {
        $flag = true;
    }       

    return $flag;
}
```

All is working fine but the issue is my custom message for `app_id.isValidTag` is not working even all other message are working fine.

Please suggest me what I missing here or in Laravel 5.2 there is some change to display message. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a great tutorial for this: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-create-custom-validation-rule-exampleexample.html

I think you did it Laravel 4.* way. This is how it is done in **Laravel 5.2**
in my example where i was making registration authorisation form so files like AuthController.php was premade:

1. AuthController.php

   ```
   Validator::make($data, [
       ...
       // add your field for validation
       'name_of_the_field' => 'validation_tag', // validation tag from validation.php
       ...
   ```
2. CustomAuthProvider.php
   // if you didn't make a custom provider use Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

   ```
   public function boot() {
       ...
       Validator::extend('validation_tag', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
               // handle here your validation
               if (  your_query ) {
                   return true;
               }
               return false;
       });
   ```
3. validation.php

   ```
   ...
   // add your validation tag and message to be displayed
   'validation_tag'           => 'The field :attribute isn't good',
   ...
   ```
4. file.blade.php
   // to add at the end of the page all your errors add

   ```
   @if (count($errors) > 0)
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                      @endforeach
                </ul>
          </div>
   @endif
   ```

Comment: You can also add the error message directly in the function using ```$validator->setCustomMessage(['<attribute>.<rule name>' => '<error message>'])```

Comment: @user3632055 if you are there i need a little help

Comment: @lewis4u whats up?

Comment: i solved my problem....but thanx....it was about the validation message for custom rule. i had localization and needed to put the message in validation.php file