# Laravel 5.2 custom validator not giving error

Tags: laravel-5

I get no errors when the validator fails. I have a function where I want to validate the request URL.

```
public function update(Request $request, RequestUser $user, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'integration_domain' => 'required',
        ]);
        //other stuff
    }
```

Below is where I have created the validator,

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Validator::extend('integration_domain', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            if((strpos($parameters->input('url'), 'localhost') !== false) || 
                (strpos($parameters->input('url'), 'http://localhost') !== false) ||  
                (strpos($parameters->input('url'), 'https://localhost') !== false) ||  
                (strpos($parameters->input('url'), '127.0.0.1') !== false) ||
                (strpos($parameters->input('url'), 'http://127.0.0.1') !== false) ||
                (strpos($parameters->input('url'), 'http://127.0.0.1') !== false))
                return false;
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812125/laravel-5-2-custom-validation-message-with-custom-validation-function) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`integration_domain` is supposed to be the `input` field name, not the rule and if its the rule then you should concatenate it with `required` like so:

```
public function update(Request $request, RequestUser $user, $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'input_variable_name' => 'required|integration_domain',
        ]);
        //other stuff
    }
```

Its basic understanding of validation. For more details please see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays)